# Git branching workflow; how to reduce number of Git commands

Tags: git, workflow, git-branch, git-flow

This is not a question about workflow opinions, but rather a specific question about how I can reduce keystrokes for the workflow below.

My dev team generally follows a customized branching Git workflow.

**Workflow**

- code is branched from `master`
- branches have a prefix `feature/<branch>`, `refactor/<branch>`, `bug/<branch>`, etc...
- code (and tests) is written for that branch
- code is submitted as Pull Request to `master`
- Pull Request is reviewed, commented, and then merged into `master`
- delete old branches and carry on

This is our workflow and it works well for us. However, the `git` commands I execute to do all of this has become fairly repetitive and a little bit annoying.

**Git Commands for Workflow**

- `git checkout -b feature/new-branch-name`
- Do some work...
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "some commit message"`
- `git push --set-upstream origin feature/new-branch-name`
- Go to Github Enterprise page, submit Pull Request for code just pushed
- Review Pull Request and Merge, Deleting branch on repo, but now have to delete locally...
- `git checkout master` (switch back to master to merge in changes)
- `git pull` (get the updates from the new branch)
- `git branch -d feature/new-branch-name` (delete local branch)
- Now I'm in a state where I can repeat it all

Is there a cleaner way to reduce so many `git` commands?  It has just gotten very tedious to repeat all of this.  I'm thinking about writing some script files that manage some of this for me.  I know there are some scripts that already exist, but I don't want to be forced into someone else's methodology, I'm really just looking for ways to save my fingers here.

Any given day I will branch and submit Pull Requests about 3-6 times.  So our branches are very short-lived and small in scale and scope.  But the actual process is arduous.

Anyone have a better implementation to accomplish my team's branching mechanism?

Comment: Have you considered leveraging Git Aliases.  Great candidates are 'checkout', 'checkout master', 'pull', 'branch -d' and 'add .'

Comment: @ThomParkin, if the only real route is to create custom commands, I would probably prefer shell scripts over git aliases. I think git aliases still have to prefix commands with "git <alias_name>".  I guess I was seeing if there was a convenient built-in way to take my workflow and establish it on Git, but it looks like I'll need to write some scripts that do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You don't need to physically update master every time you want to branch out, you can replace these steps:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout -b feature/new-branch-name
```

with:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b feature/new-branch-name origin/master
```

(these two commands are good candidate for git alias/script, called e.g. git-start-feature)

2) `git add . && git commit -m msg` is just `git commit -a -m msg`. Sometimes you will want to make single commit, sometimes split changes into many commits, so there's no point in scripting this. You can also commit any change first, and then keep amending it.

3) You don't need to delete local branch immediately, but if you want to, then you can combine this step with `git push`:

```
git push -u origin feature/new-branch-name
git checkout master
git branch -D feature/new-branch-name
```

You could turn this into script `git-push-forget`:

```
#!/bin/bash
branch_name=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
case "$branch_name" in
    master)
        echo "ops, this master!"
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        if git push -u origin "$branch_name"; then
            git checkout master
            git branch -D "$branch_name"
        else
            echo "umpf, git push failed..."
            exit 2
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

(note, that I didn't check if this script works, just typed it out online; ping me if you have any questions about it)

So now your workflow would look like this:

```
git-start feature/new-branch-name
# work, work, work
git commit -a -m "magnificent"
git-push-forget
# do github specific stuff
```

[edit]
Also, use bash completion to work fast with terminal. If you are using Linux, then make sure, that you have bash-completion (or bash-complete) packet installed - some distros may not install it by default. You can also write your own completion file (e.g to keep suggesting you branch name for git-start script). Shout out if you want to go in that direction.

Another point would be to open browser page with github pull request from git-push-forget script (if it is possible to guess url; I don't use github enterprise).

Comment: I had written some scripts that were similar to this, but you have some great ideas I didn't think about. Overall I think a custom script is the best solution as it allows each team (and developer) to tailor their approach, as long as they branch/merge back to master (for my team at least). Thanks for the ideas, I'll be updating my own scripts with some of your ideas!